# SQL all students who are older than the youngest teacher?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want all students who are older than the youngest teacher.

`select s_id, s_firstname, l_firstname
from s_schueler
where s_gebdatum<(select l_gebdatum from l_lehrer where l_gebdatum.min);`

[image]

Comment: Your subquery is incomplete. `select min(l_gebdatum) from ...?`

Comment: you're close, but the subquery is off .

Comment: What's the Problem? Edit your Question with more Details so it becomes answerable.

Comment: I want all students who are older than the youngest teacher.

Comment: So what EXACTLY does not work? give the SO-Cummunity something to work with...
or else every Answer will be a wild guess that won't help you.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'l_firstname' in 'field list'

Comment: no this is not a homework

Comment: What is you table layout ?

Comment: "Unknown column 'l_firstname' in 'field list'" - that's your column it can't find, @user3371521 - there's no value in reporting it here, since we do not know the structure of your table.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using `DESCRIBE` to get your table definitions - images aren't good either in accessibility or SEO terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select s_id, s_firstname
from s_schueler 
where s_gebdatum > (select max(l_gebdatum) from l_lehrer);
```

Assuming l_gebdatum is an age. I believe you also need a greater than symbol not a less than symbol.

Comment: s_gebdatum is not the age s_gebdatum is the date of birth of the student

Comment: I think the symbol was correct - a `datum` is a date, and so lower values are older. It's the `min` that needs to change to a `max`, since the largest values are the youngest.

Comment: Ok, you should be able to flip the sign the other way and it will return what you need. The reason why you get the error in the other question is due to that column not existing in that table. Your where clause subquery is just that, a subquery. You will not have access to that l_firstname field outside of those parentheses. Based on your original requirements that field is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select 
s_id,
s_firstname,
l_firstname -- this column should not appear here since is not a join 
from s_schueler
where 
s_gebdatum >(select min(l_gebdatum) from l_lehrer);
```

You were missing the `min()` function ! - that will retrieve the youngest teacher.

Comment: i get this error when using your code : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'l_firstname' in 'field list'

Comment: Can to place the table definition for us to see ! - because i have used the columns you have listed !

Comment: I think the `min` should be `max`, since these are dates - but +1 anyway.

Comment: @halfer - i have no idea in what language this is ! kkkkk so i have interpreted it as int.

Comment: Are you joining table ? do you have those columns on the same table ?

Comment: ive posted the table defenitions the gebdatum is the birthdate not the age

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
SELECT
    s.s_id, s.s_firstname, l.l_firstname
FROM s_schueler s
INNER JOIN (
    /* Select the youngest teacher, and alias the columns
       here in a subtable called "l" */
    SELECT MAX(l_gebdatum), l_firstname from l_lehrer GROUP BY l_firstname
) l
```

The problem with a sub-query is that you are not making the first name of your teacher available to the rest of the query. I have therefore added a join to this as a sub-select; it should not need an `ON` clause because the `MAX` forces it to have only one row.